# 'if () {} else {}' statement in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am simply trying to use an if/else statement in React in some JSX, but I get a "Parsing error: Unexpected token".  The example ternary statement seems to work fine.  Can you not use if/else statements in JSX?

```
  ./src/App.js
  Line 288:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  286 |                   { this.getInvitesForEvent(dat.id, 
  this.invitesForEventData) }
  287 |                   { true === 1 ? 'empty set' : 'has results' }
> 288 |                   { if (true) { true } else { false } }
  |                         ^
  289 |                 </div>
  290 |               ))
  291 |           }
```

Comment: Please show the code along with the error message.

Comment: You can't use statements inside JSX, only expressions. It's quite common to use ternary operator in JSX

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that inside the jsx, because only expressions can be put in jsx, not statements. If a ternary expression is inconvenient or illegible, you could consider doing an if statement outside the jsx

```
let val;
if (/*whatever*/) {
  val = true;
else {
  val = false;
}

return (
  <div>
    {val}
  </div>
)
```

As for why there's this limitation, it might help to remember what the jsx gets transpiled into. Doing `<div>Hello</div>` turns into `React.createElement("div", null, "Hello");`, and doing `<div>{true ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>` turns into `React.createElement("div", null, true ? 'true' : 'false');`

So what would `<div>{if (true) { 'true' } else { 'false ' }}</div>` transpile into? Something like `React.createElement("div", null, if (true) { 'true' } else { 'false ' });`, but it's illegal to put an if statement in the middle of that code. So it's also illegal to put it in the middle of the jsx.

Answer (score 0):

to use if/else in jsx, you can do {condition ? results : results if condition isn't met}
for example if you wanted to render the home page if someone was logged in but the login page if they weren't, you would do:

```
{ loggedIn ? <Home /> : <Login /> }
```

the "condition/variable ?" acts as a "if condition/variable" and the ":" acts as an else.